# Linux(ubuntu) MinGW | show error: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, glfw, glew

I get the error:

> fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

I don't know why, because I executes following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
```

and after seeing the error, I execute following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y
```

but it still shows the error.

My operating system: `**ubuntu16.06**`

I use `!g++ test.cpp -lGLFW -lglfw3 -lGL -lX11 -lXrandr -lXi`

the error is:

> In file included from /usr/local/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:153:0,
>                    from test.cpp:2:
>   /usr/include/GL/gl.h:6:29: fatal error: GLES/glplatform.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

My test code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include<GL/glew.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
if(!glfwInit())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
    return -1;
}
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
if(window==NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Inter GPU, they ar not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
int width, height;
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
glViewport(0,0,width,height);
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwPollEvents();
    glClearColor(0.2f,0.3f,0.3f,1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome ZMANT to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask - stack how to ask. Please show the code rather than a link - see "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: Before that I am very sorry, and now, I have changed the format of the problem description,thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to build that code and failing? Are you trying to figure out what you need to install to get this code to compile? What's the problem here? What did you do and what error messages are you getting?